# bash redirection that replaces instead of truncates

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a file `foo.txt` with a hardlink `bar.txt`. When I do

```
> foo.txt
```

The file will be truncated, but the file is till the same, therefore `bar.txt` will also e emptied out.

Is there a form of redirection that will replace the actual file entirely, or is deleting `foo.txt` beforehand the only way? The goal is to replace `foo.txt` but keep `bar.txt` with the old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is.

What you want is to get a new inode for the file `foo.txt` in order to have it independent from `bar.txt` (which is supposed to keep pointing at the original inode).  To get a new inode you first have to let go of the original inode.  There is exactly one system call for this: `unlink(2)`.  You can call this from the command line using `rm(1)` or other tools like `find -delete`.

Another way would be to rename the original file, e. g. using `mv` of course or implicitly by using sth like `cp -b`:

```
cp -b <(cat /dev/null) foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The file system doesn't distinguish between `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`; one isn't more "real" or "important" than the other, and both file-system entries refer equally to the same file. Using `>` opens the same underlying file for writing, regardless of which name you use.

What you want to do is *replace* the file system entry itself. To do that, you need a new empty file first, which you can then rename.

```
> new.txt
mv new.txt foo.txt
```